# Passing Variable with redirect in cgi/perl

Tags: perl, redirect, cgi

I have two cgi script. Login.cgi and welcome.cgi
I want to pass variable between these two pages
Here are the two pages i have

```
#!C:/Perl/bin/perl.exe -w
#login.cgi
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI::Pretty qw(:all);

my $cgi      = new CGI;
my $username = $cgi->param('username');
my $password = $cgi->param('password');

if ( ( $cgi->param('username') eq 'demo' ) && ( $cgi->param('password') eq 'demo' ) ) {
    print $cgi->redirect("welcome.cgi");
}
else {
    print header();
    print start_html( -title => "Login" );
    if ( $cgi->param('username') or $cgi->param('password') ) {
        print center( font( { -color => 'red' }, "Invalid input" ) );
    }
    print generate_form();
    print end_html();
}

sub generate_form {
    return start_form,
      h1("Please Login"),
      p( "username", textfield('username') ),
      p( "password", textfield('password') ), p(submit),
      end_form;
}
```

Another page welcome.cgi

```
#!C:/Perl/bin/perl.exe -w
#welcome.cgi
use warnings;
use CGI::Pretty qw(:all);
use strict;
my $cgi=new CGI;
my $username;
print header();
print start_html("Welcome"),h1("Hello, $username");
print end_html();
```

How do I get the username variable passed to welcome.cgi?

Comment: Please replace `my $cgi=new CGI` with `my $cgi = CGI->new`. The difference is subtle, but if you get into the habit of always calling `new` like that it will potentially save you a lot of debugging time at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`CGI::Session`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI%3a%3aSession).

For a tutorial on all the different ways to pass information between scripts and why this implementation is a good choice, read [`CGI::Session::Tutorial`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI%3a%3aSession%3a%3aTutorial)

Implemented in your login script:

```
#login.cgi
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI::Pretty qw(:all);
use CGI::Session;

my $cgi      = new CGI;
my $session  = CGI::Session->new($cgi) or die CGI->Session->errstr;
my $username = $cgi->param('username') // '';
my $password = $cgi->param('password') // '';

if ( $username eq 'demo' && $password eq 'demo' ) {
    $session->param(username => $username);
    print $cgi->redirect("welcome.cgi");
    exit;
}

print $session->header();
print start_html( -title => "Login" );
if ( $username or $cgi->param('password') ) {
    print center( font( { -color => 'red' }, "Invalid input" ) );
}
print start_form,
  h1("Please Login"),
  p( "username", textfield('username') ),
  p( "password", textfield('password') ), p(submit),
  end_form,
  end_html();
```

And in your welcome script:

```
#welcome.cgi
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI::Pretty qw(:all);
use CGI::Session;

my $cgi      = new CGI;
my $session  = CGI::Session->new($cgi) or die CGI->Session->errstr;

my $username = $session->param('username');

print header();
print start_html("Welcome"),h1("Hello, $username");
print end_html();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either pass it directly (by encoding it in a [query string](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI%3a%3aQuery) and adding that to the URL you are redirecting to) or you can store it in a [cookie](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI%3a%3aCookie) or a [session](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI%3a%3aSession) and then retrieve it in the other script.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to slightly disagree with Mr.Miller here. CGI::Session is at present outdated in many regards especially due to:

1. The method to set cookies is outdated, and does not adhere to the RFC6265
2. The Cookie ID algorithm is not secure enough, the author has moved on to other projects.

And thus should not be used unless for educational purposes.

With regards to the original question, you can look at this simple tutorial 
http://practicalperl5.blogspot.in/2014/07/perl-login-script.html

Comment: Greetings mate.  It would have been helpful to add a comment to my post about this idea, but fortunately I happened to swing by.  Anyway, I'm sure I somewhat agree with your thought (will have to read more).  However, the greater thought is that `CGI` itself is mostly outdated, which is a consideration for why it's being removed from perl core soon.  `CGI::Session` is therefore probably still the best option for tracking sessions using `CGI`, but I'd be iterested if you know any better options.

Comment: I think it would be best, if you take a look at RFC6265, to understand how cookies really work. I mean "really". 

The cookie is set during login (if success), and on members page, it is read (if it isn't, the user is redirected to front page)

To help you out, here is a little tutorial I wrote some time back:

http://rikacomet.blogspot.in/2014/01/setting-cookies-in-perl-rfc-6265.html


PS: Due to my rep being below 50, I can't comment first as per this site mechanisms. So had no choice but to reply.